# For which intial values do solutions to the 2. order ODE exist?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following problem.

"Given the differential equation:

$$x''(t)+x(t)=0$$

For which of these initial values does a solution exist?

$x(0)=5$ and   $x'(0)=4$

$x(0)=5$ and $x(2\pi)=4$

$x(0)=5$ and $x''(5)=5$

$x(0)=5$ and $x''(0)=-5$"

I feel like it's only "$x(0)=5$ and $x''(0)=-5$" that have a solution, since it's the only one who explicitly fullfil the differential equation.

Am I right in my assumption or am I missing something?

Comment: These are not all "initial values" but they are all "boundary conditions".

Comment: Huh, interesting, my professor has specifically written "initial values" for this problem. Well, now I know that.

Comment: Are you able to solve the differential equation?

Comment: Yes I believe so. I can find both the complex solution and the real solution.

Comment: Can you solve the constants of integration to make the general solution agree with the first pair of boundary conditions?

Comment: To Eric: I can try that.
To Moo: Yes, I am sure it is $x(2\pi)$. Also, it turns out the answers for this problem are the 1st and last one.

Answer (score 2):

Given differential equation is $$x''(t)+x(t)=0\implies (D^2+1)x=0\tag1$$
where $~D\equiv \dfrac{d}{dt}~$

Let $~x=e^{mt}~$ be solution of $(1)$.

Putting the value of $x$ in $(1)$ we have $$m^2+1=0\implies m=\pm ~i$$

General solution of the equation $(1)$ is $$x(t)=A\cos t+B\sin t$$where $~A,~B~$ are constants to be determined by the given conditions.

Now $$x'(t)=-A\sin t+B\cos t$$and$$x''(t)=-A\cos t -B\sin t$$

**Case I:** If possible let $x(0)=5$ and   $x'(0)=4$ are the give conditions.

Then $~x(0)=5\implies A=5~$ and $~x'(0)=4\implies B=4~$

Hence the particular solution is $$x(t)=5\cos t + 4\sin t~.$$Therefore we conclude that **this condition gives a solution**.

**Case II:** If possible let $x(0)=5$ and $x(2\pi)=4$ are the give conditions.

Then $~x(0)=5\implies A=5~$ and $~x(2\pi)=4\implies A=4~$, which is impossible.

Hence **this condition give no solution**.

**Case III:** If possible let $x(0)=5$ and $x''(5)=5$ are the give conditions.

Then $~x(0)=5\implies A=5~$ and $~x''(5)=5\implies -A\cos 5 -B\sin 5=5\implies B=-5\csc 5-5\cot 5~$

Hence the particular solution is $$x(t)=5\cos t + (-5\csc 5-5\cot 5)\sin t~.$$Therefore we conclude that **this condition gives a solution**.

**Case IV:** If possible let $x(0)=5$ and $x''(0)=-5$ are the give conditions.

Then $~x(0)=5\implies A=5~$ and $~x''(0)=-5\implies A=5~$. Here $B$ is arbitrary constant.

So in this case$$x(t)=5\cos t + B \sin t$$

Hence there are **infinitely many solution** of the given differential solution.